# Scrollable div can't be scrolled after manipulating content?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I have an iOS 6 PhoneGap app with a div with a fixed height and width and overflow-y for scrollable content. I am dynamically populating this list with content when the app loads and it works well.

However, when I manipulate the div again by emptying it's contents and replacing it with new list items, I can no longer vertically scroll. It's as if overflow-y is set to "hidden" and not "scroll".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post the html, css, and code that is handling the content transition?

Comment: what happens if you try to set the overflow-y again after manipulating the div? does that work? also what TNCodeMonkey said, post some code